# "Potency set" for power set?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, terminology

Cross-posted at [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/was-potency-set-used-for-power-set).

Has the term "potency set" been used in English language mathematics for power set, and, if so, what are good references?

It is relevant that for historical reasons, "power set" is an English translation of the German "Potenzmenge", which is still in use in German mathematical literature.

Is "potency set" advisable as a supplementary term for an operation which is sometimes like the power set, in a context where  power set of a set $a$ as $\mathcal{P}(a)=\{x|x\subset a\}$ is retained, but  $\mathcal{P}(a)$ is mathematically   idle as it is paradoxical lest $a$ is a non-paradoxical universal set?

Comment: Might be interesting in the context: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3254/3439

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Many thanks! Notice as well the German term "Potenzmenge" used for power set in German mathematical literature; I edited this into the question.

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing this term used for power set in English.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for weighing in - neither do I. May you agree that it can be an advisable supplementary term  in a context where power set of a set $a$ as $\mathcal{P}(a)=\{x|x\subset a\}$ is retained, but  $\mathcal{P}(a)$ is mathematically   idle as it is paradoxical lest $a$ is a non-paradoxical universal set?

Comment: I'm not sure I would have any special views on that case. But I think it is a fine principle in general to adopt terminology that recalls or suggests similar or related usage.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Agreed, and I will of course not attribute you a position.

Comment: Incidentally, here `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P} \quad \mathcal{P}$
\end{document}` is the symbol I was kindly helped to as an answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699976/symbol-similar-to-mathcalp

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457909/potency-set-for-power-set#comment1186259_457909), MathJax only parses inside what a TeXnician would call math mode, so it can't see the beginning and end of your TeX document.  I'm not sure if MathJax will let you load `mathalpha`, but, if it does, then you must do so as `\require`, not `\usepackage`:  $\require{mathalpha}\mathscr P\mathcal P$ `\require{mathalpha}\mathscr P\mathcal P`. (EDIT: It works!)  You can also link to [specific anwers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699989) if desired.

Comment: Even in physics, the German word *Potenz* is translated with English *power*.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Just to supplement: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/potency; https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/power

Comment: Danish, Norwegian and Swedish have "potensmængde", "potensmengde" and "potensmängd" for power set.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal: If a question is closed, please modify it *significantly* before asking the community to reopen it. Also, if the reopen request gets rejected, why try a second time?

Comment: @AlexM. That a question is closed does not mean that it should be closed. I have nothing to do with seeing a rejection, or trying something for a second time. Suggestions for improving the question are welcome, if needed.

Comment: If one is hoping to get a question re-opened without significant changes, I would suggest raising it at the [appropriate meta thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/223/4177) and discuss the finer points there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/15912/8094 was offered by kimchi lover, and accepted, at History of Science and Mathematics:

"The paper Rieger, L. "On the consistency of the generalized continuum hypothesis."*Rozprawy Mat.* 31 (1963) described in MR0146091, which can be downloaded from http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-5ca4b532-4aa3-4856-924f-8bbed25e3c33 (click on the "31. książka") uses the phrase "potency set axiom" on pp 15, 20, 38 (and maybe elsewhere)."

Ladislav Svante Rieger was Czech, and grew up in a country where German was one of the official languages. He may therefore have preferred the more literal translation.

Notice also that Bertrand Russell did not consider the term "potency set" in his 1903 book *The Principles of Mathematics*.